# On Angular JS website , cypress fails to proceed on next webpage after clicking on "search" button

Tags: angularjs, cypress

```
cy.get('button>span>.ng-star-inserted').contains('Search flights').click({force:true})
```

This click in test runner of cypress resets the webpage instead of searching the results.
I am trying the following website build in AngularJS
https://www.jetblue.com/